# Get distinct sum from an php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url_id] => 1
            [time_spent] => 41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url_id] => 2
            [time_spent] => 25
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [url_id] => 1
            [time_spent] => 41
        )
)
```

So, how to get the 'distinct' of time_spent and also the 'sum' of the time_spent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
$result = array_unique($input_array);
var_dump(array_sum($result['time_spent']));
```

**Docs:**

- [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: @vishnu: Really you needs i doubt, Accept your previous question keep in mind.

Comment: i believe that call to `array_unique` wont be effective bc it doesnt work on multi-dimensional arrays.  youd have to do it AFTER making parallel (using the term loosely) array of just time_spent values

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sum = 0;
$timeSpent = array();
foreach($myArray as $element) {
    $timeSpent[] = $element['time_spent'];
    $sum += $element['time_spent'];
}
```

To have:

1. $sum => The sum of all time_spent
2. $time_spent => An array of all time spent (whitout URL)

Comment: hey, i need distinct sum of time_spent

Answer (score 1):

```
$ts = array_map(function ($a) {return $a['time_spent'];}, $arr);  //get array of time_spent's
$sum = array_sum($ts); //sum
$distinct = array_unique($ts); //distincts
```

One-liner for sum of distinct values

```
$ans = array_sum(array_unique(array_map(function ($a) {return $a['time_spent'];}, $arr)));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php